# When start server by using `yarn start` in CRA, server is opend too slow

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, create-react-app, yarnpkg

Using CRA, server is opened after about 2 minutes!

1. Uninstall create-react-app
2. Uninstall node(npm), yarn clearly
3. Install node by using nvm
4. Install yarn using npm
5. npx create-react-app test
6. yarn test
7. same result...

node version: v12.10.0
yarn version: 1.17.3
npx version: 6.10.3

When `yarn start`,

Starting the development server...

after about 2 minutes...server open!

Before 2 week, It was so fast!

(+ macOS version: 10.14.2, 2015 early, RAM 8G)

How can I speed up my server opening?

---

It's CRA package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: sorry, 
How can I speed up my server opening?

Comment: We can not guess it from the information provided. Maybe you have added large files for the build. Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: I add it! I'm sorry, I didn't know what the problem was and didn't provide accurate information.